# WCF with Protobuf Serialization: When ignoring properties to be serialized [ProtoIgnore], do I need explicitly mark [DataMember]?

Tags: c#, wcf, serialization, protocol-buffers, protobuf-net

Working with WCF and Google Protobuf.

If I do not want  serialize a field or property, so I mark [ProtoIgnore], my question is: Do I need [DataMember]?

Which of the following examples are correct (Ignoring serializable property Name)?

Example 1

```
        [ProtoIgnore]
        [DataMember]
        public string Name { get; set; }
```

Example 2

```
        [ProtoIgnore]
        [IgnoreDataMemberAttribute]
        public string Name { get; set; }
```

Example 3

```
        [ProtoIgnore]
        [IgnoreDataMemberAttribute]
        public string Name { get; set; }
```

Example 4

```
        public string Name { get; set; }
```

Example 5

```
        [ProtoIgnore]
        public string Name { get; set; }
```

Comment: Are you using Google Protobuf (https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/tree/master/csharp) or [tag:protobuf-net] (https://github.com/mgravell/protobuf-net)?  They are different implementations of the same protocol.

Comment: I am using Google Protobuf